# Union results either Blank or Unfiltered

Tags: sql, filtering, teradata, union, where-clause

We have data that separates Paid and Rejected claims. I need to see results of both and therefore have to do a [union](/questions/tagged/union).
(Our data is a mess. I am also aliasing for confidentiality/HIPPA compliance. Please try not to get hung up on those parts because I can't change it.)

```
SELECT CustID, code, date, 'Paid' AS Srce
FROM Paid.Claims
INNER JOIN Paid.Medical
    ON Paid.Claims.id = Paid.Medical.id
    AND Paid.Claims.blind = Paid.Medical.blind
WHERE Paid.Claims.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-07'
    AND Paid.Medical.code IN ('88521','88522','88523','88524','88525')
    AND Paid.Claims.custID IN ('N065468','N095843','N001086')
UNION
SELECT CustID, code, date, 'Filter' AS Srce
FROM Rejected.Claims
INNER JOIN Rejected.Medical
    ON Rejected.Claims.id = Rejected.Medical.id
    AND Rejected.Claims.blind = Rejected.Medical.blind
WHERE Rejected.Claims.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-07'
    AND Rejected.Medical.code IN '88521','88522','88523','88524','88525')
    AND Rejected.Claims.custID IN ('N065468','N095843','N001086')
```

It's based on a query that the person before me made, and that one works but it's also much simpler because it pulls less from less places. My outcomes so far have been:

1. Leave the [where-clause](/questions/tagged/where-clause) out of the Paid data but still in the Rejected data and get EVERY RESULT. None of the [filtering](/questions/tagged/filtering) seems to be working.
2. Include the [where-clause](/questions/tagged/where-clause) in both and get no results. [filtering](/questions/tagged/filtering) not working, but in the opposite direction.

I have also tried

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    everything above with and without filters
    ) AS results
WHERE <filters same as above>
```

And results set is empty.

I have tried with and without aliasing with no changes in what's returned.

I'm expecting about 200 results that SHOULD look something like this:

```
| CustID  | code  | date       | Srce   |
| ------- | ----- | ---------- | ------ |
| N065468 | 88522 | 2022-04-04 | Paid   |
| N095843 | 88521 | 2022-03-09 | Paid   |
| N001086 | 88524 | 2022-05-20 | Filter |
```

Back to troubleshooting.

Comment: It looks odd that you are joining tables purely via their primary keys: ` Paid.Claims.PK = Paid.Medical.PK` do they really have the same primary key values (like they are partitioned)?

Comment: can you share sample data from the two tables "Paid" and "Rejected" and expected output? @MagPai

Comment: Typically one would join a (unique) primary key in one table with a (non-unique) foreign key in the other. Two tables having the same unique identifier is odd.

Comment: @Fred it's flattened/de-normalized data and it's managed by a sister company. My confusion on HOW they chose to set it up is endless.

Comment: @tinazmu it is odd. They all have two identical fields that they join on which I've tried to make more clear in my edits. It's the result of the flattening for the data mart.

Comment: @lemon added the expected output you requested. Still working on it from my end!

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but for what it's worth I can't see a reason why the code wouldn't work as-is - especially if both filtered queries run fine independently.  My guess is there's a sneaky syntax error somewhere, like a set of extra ()s , causing the where clauses to evaluate to false.  As another troubleshooting step, maybe break them both into CTEs?  `;WITH paid AS ([filtered query), rejected AS ([filtered query]), select * from paid union rejected` - if that doesnt work, run the ctes & check the output of each independently - maybe theyre both independently returning no results

Comment: @NeonTetra thanks for the suggestions, I'll keep at it.

Comment: Can I suggest that you alias every table, instead of referring to columns by a three part reference? I have seen such odd behaviour with Teradata when you simply use the full name of the table, instead of an alias.

Comment: @tinazmu thanks for the suggestion! I usually start there because our actual naming conventions get very long. The dev before me seems to have preferred not to so I was trying to use them with their full names for a bit. I'm starting to suspect that I need to start over with a different old query for a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have many duplicate fields as a result of our flattening process. My formatting may have been correct, but it turns out I was pulling from some of the wrong places. I solved the problem by creating a franken-query using several others made by my predecessor with a similar [union](/questions/tagged/union) element. Depending on how I was attempting to alias everything, the filters were likely pulling from different fields than the ones I was [select](/questions/tagged/select)-ing.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without sample data as someone else has requested. Without any data I'd recommend running each query individually and seeing what results you get ie. If you run just the top half for paid claims does that give you the rows you're expecting? Then the bottom half? The filtering arguments can be case sensitive so I'd recommend checking your medical codes are lower case.

Comment: This is not an answer with minimum requirement, please read how do I write a good answer? here :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I tried to add a comment but I'm not allowed? Should I not offer any suggestions then?

Comment: No, I appreciate it. It may not solve the problem but I have tried doing separate queries.